# Unresolved External Symbol in C++ Header

Tags: c++, header, googletest

The xyz.cpp is now throwing an unresolved external symbol for each variable defined in test.hpp despite including test.hpp. Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Test.hpp :

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <time.h>
#include <tuple>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

// Simple header to allow the transfer of command line parameters between main.cpp (where google test is run)
// and TestDuration.cpp (where the test itself is defined).
#define INTERACTIVE 0
#define COMMAND_LINE 1
#define STATIC 2

extern int runType;
extern bool clInputGiven;    // Is True only if there is command line input intended for a test.
extern double clDuration;
extern int clIterations;

#endif
```

main.cpp :

```
...
    int runType = -1;
    bool clInputGiven = false; 
    double clDuration = -1.0;
    int clIterations = -1;

...
        if (ac == 4 && av[1] == "--cl_mode")
        {
            runType = COMMAND_LINE;
            clInputGiven = true;
            clIterations = atoi(av[2]);
            clDuration = atoi(av[3]);
        }
...
```

xyz.cpp

```
...
if (runType == INTERACTIVE) {
                // Test block. Expects no throw for every iteration of calib/meas X times.
                EXPECT_NO_THROW({
...
```

The xyz.cpp and main.cpp just have a simple #include "test.h" at the beginning.

My question(s) :
1. I assume that I'm not understanding how includes really work, so any in-depth explanation would be helpful.
2. If the header file method will cause too many issues, how would you go about passing arguments from main.cpp to xyz.cpp?

If you need more info, just ask. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: We need to see how you compile that, as well as a [mcve]. Also, something tells me gtest is irrevelant.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would've redone it, but I figured it out. I used cmake to build it, though I verified that the build tool isn't the problem. Gtest is/was relevant because of the original question (gtest does not allow you to directly pass command line args to the tests themselves, so I was trying to find a workaround by using a header. Hacky I know, but its the best I could think of while still giving us the utility that gtest provides).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out after enough experimentation. Thanks to @Ron for the help. I apologize for rephrasing the question (didn't know that it would erase your answer).

If you run into the same problem...

I ended up putting #pragma once at the top of the header file, declaring each variable with extern in the header file, then explicitly defining each variable in the global scope of main.cpp (outside / above of the main method).

pragma once tells the preprocessor to only include the file once in a compilation. It acts the same as include guards, but with less code. Extern tells the program that the variable is defined / stored somewhere else in the code.

Hope that helps anyone who runs into the same problem in the future!

Comment: Ron probably removed his answer manually. You can't do that with an edit, that would be silly.